# Number of words from given consonants and vowels

Tags: combinatorics

How many words of 4 consonants and 2 vowels can be formed out of 6 consonants and 3 vowels
(A) 90 (B) 720 (C) 64000 (D) 64800

To me problem appears fairly simple if we assume repetition is not allowed. In that case total number of words formed will be $C(6,4)*C(3,2)*6!=32400$ which doesn't match with any of the given options.

Considering repetition, gives us 5*2=10 separate cases and in that case answer is greater than 64800.

Question was asked in ISI MSQMS QMA 2021 paper. I wish to confirm if the answer to this question is indeed wrong

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: I agree with your computations.